# How to verify if a page is cache-able?

Tags: embedded-linux

For a given virtual address 'addr' I'd like to check if the page address 'addr' is in, is cache-able?

Motivation: I'd like to verify certain attributes as cache-able, readable, writable, executable.

How can I do that?